# PHP-PKPass Not working with iOS 7 add the date and time that the pass was signed using the S/MIME signing-time attribute in PHP

Tags: php, ios, ssl, passbook

Hi im new to ios 7 and php
ive been trying to make this [PHP-PKPass Class](https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass) to work with ios 7 it works fine with my Safari browser I can visualize the ticket when i try to download the package to add it to my passbook safari tells me "Cannot download the file"
this is the link where it have the [sample running with my certificates](http://www.rivertechservices.com/passbookpass/index.php) 
i looked into the phone logs it says:

The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.

all my certificates work fine the json is correct since i can visualize it on my Mac, the research that ive done so far points to the package needing to be signed with with the server date time not enforced in ios 6 but enforced in ios 7

anybody can help out with adding the date and time that the pass was signed using the S/MIME signing-time attribute via php to the current php class?

```
 protected function createSignature($manifest) {
            $paths = $this->paths();

            file_put_contents($paths['manifest'], $manifest);

            $pkcs12 = file_get_contents($this->certPath);
            $certs = array();
            if(openssl_pkcs12_read($pkcs12, $certs, $this->certPass) == true) {
                    $certdata = openssl_x509_read($certs['cert']);
                    $privkey = openssl_pkey_get_private($certs['pkey'], $this->certPass );

                    if(!empty($this->WWDRcertPath)){

                            if(!file_exists($this->WWDRcertPath)){
                                    $this->sError = 'WWDR Intermediate Certificate does not exist';
                                    return false;
                            }

                            openssl_pkcs7_sign($paths['manifest'], $paths['signature'], $certdata, $privkey, array(), PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED, $this->WWDRcertPath);
                    }else{
                            openssl_pkcs7_sign($paths['manifest'], $paths['signature'], $certdata, $privkey, array(), PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED);
                    }

                    $signature = file_get_contents($paths['signature']);
                    $signature = $this->convertPEMtoDER($signature);
                    file_put_contents($paths['signature'], $signature);

                    return true;
            } else {
                    $this->sError = 'Could not read the certificate';
                    return false;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing your certificates and keys in as file references.  E.g.

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign($paths['manifest'],
            $paths['signature'],
            'file://' . $certs['cert'],
            array('file://' . $certs['cert'], $this->certPass),
            array(),
            PKCS7_BINARY|PKCS7_DETACHED,
            $this->WWDRcertPath);
```

Comment: im still getting the same error, it looks like apple changed something i tried a new passkit library http://cdn.simon.waldherr.eu/projects/passkit.php same error "Cannot download file"

Comment: What do the console logs of the device say (turn on Passbook logging from the developer menu on the device and monitor in Xcode).  If you can't see the device logs, can you post a link to your .pkpass bundle and I can take a look.

Comment: sample running with my certificates http://www.rivertechservices.com/passbookpass/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I created a new pass ID, generated a new p12 certificate it works now!!!
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: How did you get it to work? After using @passkit's answer desktop safari shows a billion php issues and all of the data is garbled :(